# Can I reconfigure two 5" ducts into a single line & what size should they be?

Tags: hvac, heating, air-conditioning, ducts, cooling

I am trying to move a floor register location.  Currently I have two 5" HVAC ducts being fed from a 6" x 10" rectangular trunk.  The one 5" run has the register in the middle of the room.  I would like to know if I can remove one of the two 5" duct runs, and add a tee to the 2nd run to extend that run to the 2nd register in the other room.  This would allow me to have the 2nd register under the window instead of in the middle of the room.  If I can tee from the first register, is it recommended to keep the entire run at 5", or should I reduce the run to 4" after the first register so as to not steal too much of the flow from the first register?

Comment: A diagram would help you help us.

Comment: In reality it's not going to be enough. To actually have to reduce duct size would mean someone balanced the crap out of that system. Which I guess is a possibility as you've 5" (means someone actually did their home work, because that's not a standard size). - First register might need turning veins, and the one at the end might need a balance plate. - You're trying to put two registers on a *not even* 6"? That's a no. Remove half of the cross section of the supply; cuts the supply in half. And then there's the drag on the inside walls which gets worse the smaller you go, especially on round

Comment: https://hvacdirect.com/hvac/pdf/Field_duct-sizing-chart.pdf - 5" round is 50 cfm. You need 8x4 square for 110 cfm. - Or custom 24 by 2? (extra wide because there's a horrible skin effect in there). - Or 7" round for 110cfm.

Comment: Over all its not a very long run so I suppose I could upsize the 5" round run off the 6x10 trunk to 8x4 up to the first register and then carry on with 5" round duct from there to the 2nd register.